# unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier interface

Tags: android, hostname, android-security

I developed the app and published the google play store then received the notification from Google
[image]

HostnameVerifier
Your app(s) are using an unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier interface. You can find more information about how to resolve the issue in this Google Help Center article, including the deadline for fixing the vulnerability.

I can't use HostnameVerifier or call `setDefaultHostnameVerifier()`, I assume it relies upon some 3rd party lib. Third parties lib used- `Google map, baidu map, firebase crash analytics, firebase phone authentication, quick blox, mob authentication`.

I tried to use these code in splash to solve this issue-

```
HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
        socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) hostnameVerifier);
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443));
        SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(client.getParams(), registry);
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, client.getParams());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
```

And

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(final String hostname, final SSLSession session) {



                if (session.isValid()) {

                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }`
```

But, my app got rejected from Google play store.

Please, help me in finding whats wrong with this code? and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Just remove all of it and use the default.  You don't need to specify a specific one.  If for some reason you actually don't have a certificate and need to accept unsigned certs-  just buy a certificate.  It costs like 10 bucks these days.  Google will not accept any app that accepts certs blindly.

Comment: Sorry but not getting what to remove and how to use default @Gabe Sechan

Comment: Just remove all of that code. There's a default verifier used if none is specified. It will accept any certificate by a reputable signing authority

Comment: we tried it earlier . Earlier there was no code but still google rejected the app

Comment: Then they rejected it for something else, or you didn't remove the important line. I have apps out three right now with no custom verifier, happily accepted

Comment: I am having the same issue. I am using retrofit and okHttp3 to make API calls. I dont have any default verifier set. Was this issue solved?

Comment: Facing the same issue, any help available?

Comment: @KanwarpreetSingh it is likely that some library that your app includes does the wrong thing.

Comment: @Alex Cohn Yeah, It was BrineTree Payment gateway

Answer (score 2):

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                // could judge
                if (hostname.equals("xx.xx.xx.xx")) {
                    return true;
                } else {`enter code here`
                    return false;
                }
            }
});
```

According to Google's tips, the solution is to determine the host code name HTTPS connection, if this is their expectations. Prevent middle attacks.